# Which locale is used for kotlin's string templates?

Tags: format, kotlin

The [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#string-templates) does not cover which locale is used to convert variables to strings. An example:

```
val d = 0.1234
val s = "$d"
```

Will `s` be `0.1234` or `0,1234` which reflects my machine's local (`de_AT`)?

Any means to adjust it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TL;DR: you can not adjust it.

If you look at the bytecode when you use string interpolation, you'll see that it uses `StringBuilder` under the hood (which is the same as what modern Java compilers do with `+` concatenation).

Just as an example, if you take this code:

```
val kt = "Kotlin"
println("hello $kt")
```

The string template operation looks like this in the bytecode (which is moderately legible):

```
LINENUMBER 8 L2
NEW java/lang/StringBuilder
DUP
INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/StringBuilder.<init> ()V
LDC "hello "
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
ALOAD 1
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.toString ()Ljava/lang/String;
ASTORE 2
```

Back to the point. So now the question is what `StringBuilder` uses when you append a `double` to it. If you look up the documentation, it uses the `String.valueOf(double)` method, which in turn uses `Double.toString(double)`, for which you can find the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double)) to see how it formats the values given to it. Short summary: it uses `.` as the decimal separator, and gives you exponential notation with `E` for very small and very large numbers.

The documentation in the last link suggests to use [`NumberFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) if you want to format it differently. I'd also suggest [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)), which you can pass a [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to.

Comment: thanks @zsmb13, clever idea to use the bytecode for inspection.